# how to open useDetailPopup on right-click in tui-calendar?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to open the detail popup on right-click but it doesn't work... if anyone faces this type of issue please let me know.[open detail popup on right-click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwzH3.png)......[on right-click controller menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwv0m.png)....[get_Arrow_Direction function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjjhY.png)

Comment: So what exactly is the error you that you get, what is your code (can you not link code in screenshots/images) ?

Comment: i don't get any error it just didn't work on right-click, on right-click it always open controller menu. I also attach a code screenshot, if you click on link the code screenshot will open

Comment: Ok so that code in your screenshot doesn't do much except set a variable, add some CSS classes, add a CSS border value. Not seeing anything that would handle a click, nor a right click at that. Can you point me in the direction in that code to where it does what you are describing?

Comment: Anyways I think you had posted something but maybe deleted it, but I submitted an answer that may help point you in the right direction, because I don't see this ever working without having some `event` waiting for the click to happen

Comment: my problem related to toast UI calendar when i click on shift the popup open but i want to open that popup on right-click but it open on left click even i changed the arrow-left to arrow-right....i don't know how to share file or code if i tried to paste code it doesn't allow me i am new here

Answer (score 0):

#### To specifically capture the mouse right-click, JavaScript has a special event for that - contextmenu.

So I don't see any reference to an event listener for `click` or most likely for your case, `contextmenu`

Take a look at this [blog post by Nikita Hlopov](https://nikitahl.com/detect-mouse-right-click-with-javascript#:%7E:text=To%20specifically%20capture%20the%20mouse,can%20specify%20the%20contextmenu%20event.&text=This%20event%20still%20has%20the,value%20of%20the%2C%20clicked%20button.) for more information about the `contextmenu`.

Depending on the situation, instead of identifying which button has been clicked, you can specify the `contextmenu` event.

```js
// add event listener for right clicking on the page
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
  console.log(event.button)
});
```

This `event` still has the `button` property, with the number value of the, clicked button.

Additionally, if you need to prevent further action, you can specify the `e.preventDefault()` without checking against a button property.

Comment: i am using toast UI calendar package, according to package popup open on left click but i want to open popup on right-click.. if you have a knowledge of package ever you used for calendar or please share your ideas